# TokenAccountNotFoundError in getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount

Tags: web3.js

I want to transfer custom spl-token by '@solana/web3.js'.

I call a function getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount. It returns TokenAccountNotFoundError

```
  const connection = new Connection('https://api.devnet.solana.com', 'confirmed');
  const adminPubKey = new PublicKey(my wallet publicKey);
  const mintAccount = await getMintAccount(tokenId);
  const { signTransaction } = useWallet();

  const adminTokenAccount = await findATA(
    connection,
    adminPubKey,
    new PublicKey(mintAccount.toString()),
    adminPubKey,
    signTransaction, // 
  );
```

```
const findATA = async (connection, payer, tokenMintAddress, walletAddress, signTransaction) => {
  return await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
    connection,
    payer,
    tokenMintAddress,
    walletAddress,
    signTransaction,
  );
};
```

it always returns null.

Comment: PS you don't need to `return await` since the function that calls `findATA()` is already awaiting the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 5th argument of the `getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount` function is optional and when used is a boolean type that specifies whether or not the owner of the ATA is a PDA. You typically don't need more than 4 arguments but when you do use the 5th it should be a bool and wouldn't match `signTransaction` here.

Call it like this instead:

```
return await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
    connection,
    payer,
    tokenMintAddress,
    walletAddress,
  );
```

Comment: Thx. I fix it. However, there is an error until now..

Comment: Is there still an error? What is it?