# getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount() throws TokenAccountNotFoundError

Tags: associated-token-account, javascript, react, spl-associated-token-account

I am trying to figure out why `createAssociatedAccount` does not work. This is the code:

```
const SendTransaction = ({ children }) => {
const { connection } = useConnection();
const { publicKey, signTransaction } = useWallet();

const onSendSPLTransaction = useCallback(async () => {

try {
  if (!publicKey || !signTransaction) throw new WalletNotConnectedError();

  const toPublicKey = new PublicKey("string pubkey is here");
  
  const tokenPublicKey = new PublicKey("another is here");

  const fromTokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
    connection,
    publicKey,
    tokenPublicKey,
    publicKey,
    signTransaction 
  );
  // this console.log confirms that getAccount went well
  console.log(fromTokenAccount.address.toBase58());
  
  // from here the code fails
  const toTokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
    connection,
    publicKey,
    tokenPublicKey,
    toPublicKey,
    signTransaction 
  );
  ...
})
```

When I run this function, I can observe that the `fromTokenAccount` part has no problems, and I can confirm that it gets the correct ATA Pubkey (confirmed in explorer). However, for some reason, I receive `TokenAccountNotFoundError` when the `toTokenAccount` runs...

Please, help me to understand what is going on ---  I believe that I am doing something dumb here.

`EDIT`: When I change the payer from the one I got from `useWallet()` hook to the hardcoded Keypair, the whole function works. So, what am I missing here? Have any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TokenAccountNotFoundError in getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/2465/tokenaccountnotfounderror-in-getorcreateassociatedtokenaccount)

Answer (score 1):

Could be that your callback function is not updating when the wallet changes (e.g. when it connects).

More likely you need a payer and you have a pubkey instead. `getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount` expects a Keypair for the payer arg, you have a pubkey. You can modify the source code of getOrCreate to do the same thing:

```
let ixes: TransactionInstruction[] = [];
const ata = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(
    mint,
    owner,
    allowOwnerOffCurve,
    programId,
    associatedTokenProgramId
);
let ataAcc = await getAccount(connection, ata);
  if (!ataAcc) {
    ixes.push(
      createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
        wallet.publicKey,
        ata,
        owner,
        tokenMint
      )
    );
  }
// Append this ix before whatever ix you are actually sending to send the create ATA ix as needed...
// e.g. tx.add(...ixes);
```

Answer (score 0):

check if you're using the correct token mint

```
 // from here the code fails
  const toTokenAccount = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
    connection,
    publicKey,
    tokenPublicKey,// it should token mint
    toPublicKey,
    signTransaction 
  );
```

if tokenPublicKey is not the token mint, there would be a problem

Comment: Thank you for the response! The token mint is correct. As we get the correct ATA in the previous step (given the same tokenPublicKey)

Comment: i think you've answered the question yourself . Actually, the getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount function expects user keypair and not a publickey. as it'll be used to pay for transaction and initialization fees. and you cant do that with just a PublicKey

Comment: I've written a detailed answer here, do check https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/2814/how-to-transfer-spl-tokens/3542#3542